# Parallel.For using step != 1

Tags: c#, for-loop, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

Is there any way to achieve the `Parallel.For` version of this `for` loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 2) { DoStuff(i); }
```

I don't see an overload which accepts a step parameter, though I can't think of any reason this would be logically impossible.

The accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142446/parallel-for-step-size) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980300/changing-the-incremental-value-of-a-c-sharp-parallel-for-loop) question suggests using `Parallel.ForEach` on a range of `int`s generated using `Enumerable.Range`, but in my case I am using thread local data <strike>so `Parallel.ForEach` is not an option</strike>.

Another option is to just check if `i % 2 == 0` in the body of my loop and `return`, but this still executes the thread local data intializer `Func` and finalizer `Func`. Below is a code snippet demonstrating this option:

```
Parallel.For<Bar>(0, limit, 

    () => new Bar(), //thread local data initialize

    (i, state, local) => //loop body
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0) return local;
        local.foo += DoStuff(i);
        return local;
    },

    (local) => //thread local data post-action
    {
        lock (loopLocker)
        {
            globalData.foo += local.foo;
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a hint:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) { i = 2*j; DoStuff(); }
```

In general, see if you can figure out the number of iterations and a transformation from iteration number to the variable value.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another way to process stepped indexes:

```
private void ParallelForEachProcessSteppedIndexes()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(SteppedIterator(0, 100, 2), (index) => DoStuff(index));
}

private static IEnumerable<int> SteppedIterator(int startIndex, int endIndex, int stepSize)
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i = i + stepSize)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ben's suggestion is very good for constant step e.g. +2, +3 etc.

Alternatively (if your step is random) you could use `Parallel.ForEach` e.g.

```
int[] input = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 20, 25 }; 

Parallel.ForEach(input,
    () => new Bar(), //thread local data initialize
    (i, state, local) => //loop body
    {
        // your code
    },
    (local) => //thread local data post-action
    {
        // your code
    }
```

Variable `i` will get data from `input` array. You could replace `input` with `Enumerable.Range` (or combine it with `With` etc.)

That would work perfectly fine if you would like to get only prime number in `i` variable.

Comment: I don't know why I previously missed the thread local overloads of `Parallel.ForEach`, I thought thread locality was only available in `Parallel.For`. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Toan's answer worked for me after converting to VB.NET's new Iterator function

```
Private Sub LoopExample()
    Parallel.ForEach(SteppedIterator(1,100,5), AddressOf Test)

End Sub

Private Iterator Function SteppedIterator(startIndex As Integer, endIndex As Integer, stepSize As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
    For i As Integer = startIndex To endIndex Step stepSize
        Yield i
    Next

End Function

Private Sub Test(i As Integer, state As ParallelLoopState, index As Long)
    Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString)
End Sub
```